# How to do ADB driver installation and device activation? (For Phone/PC App installation enabling)

Tags: android, adb, device

I have trouble in  ADB driver installation and device activation.

While many suggest activating USB debugging mode etc, the solution is not working in many devices.

I have Redmi Note 7. Redmi's site gives a suggestion, but that solution is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below process works for all models.

First try your OEM phone maker suggestion. Can be accessed through this link (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb)

If they don't work, follow below procedure.

1. Download Device ADB(Android Debug Bridge) Driver from maker website
2. Unzip and paste to desktop
3. Open Device Manager
4. Under Action Menu button, click Add Legacy Hardware
5. Follow procedure and manually locate local driver files
6. Point to android_winusb file and proceed with OK Next Next.
7. Finally, the device will be installed.